# Save layout with expanded folders in Windows Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I expand 'My computer' to have quick access to the hard drives on the left side, the next time when I open my computer the folders are closed.

[image: expanded]
[image: not expanded]

I tried to not close 'My computer' window after expanding and then restarted 'explorer.exe' but it is still same. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 for Windows 7 without third party tools:
a) create a Desktop shortcut to "explorer.exe ," (found on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html))
b) in the context menu of the task bar, enable "Quick Launch"
c) move the shortcut to "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch" for easy access

Method 2 is better, because this will work for the default Windows Explorer shortcut in taskbar **and** <kbd>Win-E</kbd>:
a) [upgrade to Windows 10 for free](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-download-windows-10-for-free-now-that-windows-7-is-dead/) (also to receive security updates)
b) go to Windows Explorer options and instead of "Quick access" choose "This PC"
[image: Folder Options]

Method 3 is better, because this will also work for the default Windows Explorer shortcut in taskbar **and** <kbd>Win-E</kbd>:
a) [upgrade to Windows 10 for free](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-download-windows-10-for-free-now-that-windows-7-is-dead/) (also to receive security updates)
b) go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID in regedit
- create the 4 keys {52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\opennewwindow\command
- create an empty string DelegateExecute
- add the command line from method 1 to the (Default)
Method 3 is just more flexible than method 2, because it also can be used to default to the documents folder.
[image: regedit]

Found the method 2/3 [here](https://winaero.com/blog/make-explorer-open-custom-folder-instead-of-this-pc-or-quick-access-in-windows-10/) and [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/winkey-e-shortcut-target-change/), but did not need a VBS as they describe.